# Post thumbnail not working on wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I'm creating my own custom wordpress theme.

This is what my theme's index.php has:

```
 <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            </span>
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="thumb"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>" /></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="post">
                <?php get_the_content(400, "Read more"); ?> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>.
            </div<br/>
```

My functions.php file has this:

```
 <?php

 add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post' ) );
 the_post_thumbnail( array(80,80) );

 ?>
```

My site shows this (the image doesn't load):

```
 <a href="http://ipadappbuzz.com/?p=1" class="thumb"><img src="<img width="50" height="50" src="http://ipadappbuzz.com/wp-content/uploads/article-new_ehow_images_a00_05_uu_decorate-outdoors-halloween-800x800-50x50.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="article-new_ehow_images_a00_05_uu_decorate-outdoors-halloween-800x800" title="article-new_ehow_images_a00_05_uu_decorate-outdoors-halloween-800x800" />" /></a>
                            <div class="post">
                 <a href="http://ipadappbuzz.com/?p=1">Read more</a>.
```

Not sure why the image source isn't loading correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have the img src attribute pointing to a string definition of another img:

```
<a href="http://ipadappbuzz.com/?p=1" class="thumb"><img src="<img width="50" height="50" src="http://ipadappbuzz.com/wp-content/uploads/article-new_ehow_images_a00_05_uu_decorate-outdoors-halloween-800x800-50x50.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="article-new_ehow_images_a00_05_uu_decorate-outdoors-halloween-800x800" title="article-new_ehow_images_a00_05_uu_decorate-outdoors-halloween-800x800" />" /></a>
                            <div class="post">
                 <a href="http://ipadappbuzz.com/?p=1">Read more</a>.
```

This is the offending line:

```
<img src="<img width="50" height="50" src="http://ipadappbuzz.com/wp-content/uploads/article-new_ehow_images_a00_05_uu_decorate-outdoors-halloween-800x800-50x50.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="article-new_ehow_images_a00_05_uu_decorate-outdoors-halloween-800x800" title="article-new_ehow_images_a00_05_uu_decorate-outdoors-halloween-800x800" />" />
```

It needs to be corrected to the following - or something to that effect:

```
<img width="50" height="50" src="http://ipadappbuzz.com/wp-content/uploads/article-new_ehow_images_a00_05_uu_decorate-outdoors-halloween-800x800-50x50.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="article-new_ehow_images_a00_05_uu_decorate-outdoors-halloween-800x800" title="article-new_ehow_images_a00_05_uu_decorate-outdoors-halloween-800x800" />
```

Now, as for the code that is generating this:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

I don't know what `the_permalink()`, `the_title_attribute()`, or `the_title()` functions are, and how you've defined them and what they return. **But, my suspicion is that you've introduced an extra closing tag somewhere**.

UPDATE:

From the code the original poster has updated me with, I think you should have your PHP code as follows:

" class="thumb">"

Since it seems as though the_post_thumbnail() is echoing / returning an img:

```
<img width="50" height="50" src="http://ipadappbuzz.com/wp-content/uploads/article-new_ehow_images_a00_05_uu_decorate-outdoors-halloween-800x800-50x50.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="article-new_ehow_images_a00_05_uu_decorate-outdoors-halloween-800x800" title="article-new_ehow_images_a00_05_uu_decorate-outdoors-halloween-800x800" />
```

Comment: Well the code I have in my theme file is:

     <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="thumb"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>" /></a>
    <?php endif; ?>

So it literally should parse and load up a source code like this: <a href="link"><img src="image url"></a> but for some odd reason, the image code duplicates and places itself inside of another existing image code which I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: If possible, could you post that too?

Comment: I pressed the enter button too soon hehe.  Read my reply.

Comment: Got it to work....<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>  I turned the <img src= part and just turned the img code into a php snippet since the snippet itself was generating the image code.